# docker images list showing no results even with container running

Tags: docker, containers, docker-container, docker-image

I have this:

```
> docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
edf86b00c790        mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CTP2.2-ubuntu   "/opt/mssql/bin/sqls…"   3 weeks ago         Up 6 days           0.0.0.0:3341->1433/tcp   sql2019

PS C:\Users\User
> docker images ls -a
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

PS C:\Users\User
>
```

Trying to understand how I can be running an image that doesn't appear in the images list.

I'm running

> > docker --version Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command to list images is: `docker images`

Comment: Ah yes!  Tripped up by the inconsistency between the container and images commands.

Comment: Or `docker image ls -a`